# IE8 won't style figcaption element using JQuery and html5shiv

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a JQuery script that manipulates the DOM to create a `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to style the `<figcaption>` using CSS, in IE8. The same code works fine for Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas why IE8 won't style the elements?

I'm using the HTML5Shiv script with IE8, so it should recognize the new HTML5 elements and allow me to style them. Here is the code, and thanks for checking it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>     
<title>Untitled</title>
<style>
    body {
               width: 600px;
               margin-left: auto;
               margin-right: auto;
    }
    figure {
              float: left;
    }
    figcaption {
              display: block; 
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 0.5em; 
              font-style: italic;
              font-weight: bold;
              padding: 5px 0;
   }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="This should be bold, italic, centered and small" />

<p>This is a regular paragraph.</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').wrap('<figure></figure>');
$('img').after('<figcaption>This should be bold, italic, centered and small</figcaption>');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try with `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [HTML5 innerShiv](http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/) to style dynamic HTML5 elements.

Comment: I suspected it was a problem with IE8 not being able to style dynamically generated HTML5 elements. The HTML5InnerShiv script seems to work OK for simple cases. My "real" script is a lot bigger and it's not worth the trouble to modify it so it will work with innerShiv. But, it's nice to know the answer. Thanks!

Comment: InnerShiv is now obsolete. THe most current version of html5shiv will work properly [http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the shiv js has to process all the elements before the CSS is applied (note it doesn't work if you place the shiv js below the CSS)

therefore when you add the elements after the document has loaded the shiv js does not rerun to reprocess them (sorry about my terminology!)

it works fine if you change `figure` and `figcaption` to divs with classes and add the same classes to `figure` and `figcaption` in the CSS, but you probably already knew that.. just in case..e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').wrap('<div class="figure"></div>');
$('img').after('<div class="figcaption">This should be bold, italic, centered and small</div>');
});


figure, .figure {
          float: left;
}
figcaption, .figcaption {
          display: block; 
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 0.5em; 
          font-style: italic;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 5px 0;
```

}

you could if you want to be pure only feed the div version to IE , the page will still "validate" html5, or could you add the empty elements to the page at the same time as the image, then fill them via jQuery?